# Vivaldi browser confirmation dialog opens up tabs indefinitely

Tags: vivaldi

I'm using Vivaldi browser 3.6 and when I try to download a "dangerous" file (any executable), I get a confirmation dialog:

[image]

Unfortunately, as the dialog is open, new tabs are opening *automatically* in the background.

When I started this post, I had 570 open tabs.

[image]

And it doesn not stop until I press either Keep or Cancel.

Unfortunately, either action closes my browser instantly. When I restart my browser, it reopens the downloading page so I get the confirmation dialog again.

The memory has run out at 626 tabs:

[image]

So, can you tell me how can I keep my Vivaldi browser downloading executables *normally*?

Comment: Have you tried updating Vivaldi to 3.7?  Have you reported this issue to Vivaldi? Does this happen with a new Vivaldi user profile?  You can [edit] your question to include this vital information

Comment: try downloading files using "Save As...". Notifications about file security should not appear. But for now here is how it is - If you enable phishing protection in the settings (this is a built-in Google tool) - this warning does not appear, because the browser checks in the Google database the safety of this file. And if you disable the protection option, then the browser starts to scare you with downloaded *.exe, because it can't check them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks that **Vivalid 3.7** has finally managed to solve this so I can confirm the download without crash and additional tabs.